# How to prove a property of a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[This problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard) suggests that it is possible for any positive integer $N$ to have all combinations of digits in base $10$ representation of $N, \ 2N, \ 3N, ...$. For instance,

$N=1692, 2N = 3384, 3N = 5076$

How can we prove this?

Answer (score 3):

We'll see every digit as the first digit once we get to multiples of $N$ that are much larger than $N$. Specifically, if $N$ is a $d$-digit number, then once we get to $(d+1)$-digit numbers, we can't skip any first digits.

For example, with $1692$, we'll have a first digit of $1$ for a while (with $10152, 11844, \dots$) then get to a first digit of $2$ (with $20304, 21996, \dots$), then a first digit of $3$, and so on.

We can't skip a first digit because that would require us to go up by at least $10^d$, but $N < 10^d$ if $N$ is a $d$-digit number.

This leaves only $0$ to find as a digit, but we can definitely find $0$ in $10N$.

Of course, in many cases, we'll see all the digits much sooner than this.

Comment: Nice. You will have seen every non-zero digit at the front of a number by $81N$.

Comment: The actual theoretical maximum appears to be that when $N=125$, we need to go as far as $72N$ before we see all the digits.

Comment: Sounds right, I was just looking at your neat limiting method of getting the first digit to every different possibility.